# My SQS queue doesn't show any messages in flight from aws-sdk with node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-sqs, aws-sdk-js

My code is

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
AWS.config.update({ accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY })
const sqs = new AWS.SQS({ region: 'us-east-1' })

  return Promise.map(utxos, (utxo) => {
    console.log({
      QueueUrl: process.env.SQS_URL,
      MessageBody: {
        txid: utxo.txid,
        CurrencyId: CurrencyId,
        address: utxo.address
      }
    })

    return sqs.sendMessage({
      QueueUrl: process.env.SQS_URL,
      MessageBody: JSON.stringify({
        txid: utxo.txid,
        CurrencyId: CurrencyId,
        address: utxo.address
      })
    }, (err, response) => {
      console.log('err', err)
      console.log('response', response)
    })
  })
```

However, when I look in my aws console, I don't see any messages. I'm using a standard queue, not a FIFO one.

What could be wrong?

The 2 console.log's never print. But the first one does with all the correct parameters.

Comment: Sure the env vars are populated? also, try logging the message with console.log. Maybe the message is not defined.

Comment: Yup - the env is populated and the message is defined as well

Comment: `sqs.sendMessage()` is asynchronous.  Provide a callback function and check the response.

Comment: Did that too... nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you are not returning in a promise inside the `Promise.map`

wrapping your sqs code like this should work

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
  sqs.sendMessage({
    QueueUrl: process.env.SQS_URL,
    MessageBody: JSON.stringify({
      txid: utxo.txid,
      CurrencyId: CurrencyId,
      address: utxo.address
    })
  }, (err, response) => {
    console.log('err', err)
    console.log('response', response)
    if(err)(reject(err))
    resolve(response);
  })
});
```